# Share Xcode assets catalog between projects

Tags: swift, frameworks, xcode6, asset-catalog

In their [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html) apple states that -

> You can share asset catalogs across multiple projects in the same workspace.

I have a project in a workspace with multiple targets and an other project in the same workspace that I want to use to share it's catalog with all the targets of his neighbour project.

SharedProject(Framework)

--AssetsCatalog

MainProject

--Target1

--Target2

--etc

Any one has managed to do so and help ?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.

I have a workspace with different projects.

My solution:

1. Open your workspace in Xcode
2. Add a new asset catalog to your workspace "newSharedAssets.xcasstes"
3. Now go to projectA and add asset catalog by using right-click "Add Files to projectA" (only add as reference)
4. Now go to projectB and add asset catalog by using right-click "Add Files to projectB" (only add as reference)

Does it help you?

Comment: When archiving the app, it makes a copy of the whole catalog into each module/framework that has it's reference, increasing the app size.